# Why autoconf.h is not copied automatically to its place?

Tags: linux, debian, linux-kernel, compiling

I'm working on a clean Debian 7.7 install. After the install everything was working fine except the webcam in Iceweasel browser. After reading a lot I found that the best solution is to install [FlashCam 1.4.5](http://www.swift-tools.net/Flashcam/).

```
After downloading the sources, I did a make and got an error:

  ERROR: Kernel configuration is invalid.
         include/generated/autoconf.h or include/config/auto.conf are missing.
         Run 'make oldconfig && make prepare' on kernel src to fix it.


  WARNING: Symbol version dump /usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-4-common/Module.symvers
           is missing; modules will have no dependencies and modversions.

  Building modules, stage 2.
```

Read something and found that I must install the kernel sources and prepare to compile:

```
apt-get install linux-source linux-source-3.2
tar jxf /usr/src/linux-source-3.2.tar.bz2
cd linux-source-3.2
cp /boot/config-3.2.0-4-amd64 ./.config
make oldconfig
make prepare
```

Now there is an autoconf.h file in my local `linux-sources` folder (`linux-sources/include/generated/autoconf.h`) but not in `*/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-4-common/include/*` where I assume is the folder where FlashCam sources are looking for. What should I do now? Copy by hand this folder is a bit scary and I can't find additional instructions to make it work.

Comment: A pair of quotes from the flashcam page you linked to: `Last update: $Date: 2010-08-07 07:45:35 $ (UTC)` and `Flash 10 (aka Astro) Beta 2 is out and is supposed to support V4L2. At last! I guess Flashcam won't be useful for long on the desktop.` If that's the best solution you're in trouble.

Comment: Upss.. The weird is I've read it as a solution in some articles more recents than 2010. Anyway, the question is independent of the FlashCam software, maybe in the future I need to recompile something that uses these files and I'd like to know what's happening. Thanks.

Comment: I have the same issue. Is it resolved ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Up to date instructions for building out-of-tree kernel modules are [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kbuild/modules.txt). Installing the kernel config headers to the system include directory is not part of the procedure. Rather you invoke `make` from inside the kernel source tree and point it to the module's source tree with the `M=` parameter.

FlashCam hasn't been updated in a while so it may not be possible to build it against a recent kernel without some porting effort.